# I'm not a robot!

Tags: support

When I try to ask a question, it says "it did not meet our quality standards." Clicking again takes me to a CAPTCHA. Then back to the original screen.
What's wrong here? What kind of "quality standard"?

Comment: I think Kim Lee figured it out for question 71...

Comment: Let's find out.... You’re in a desert walking along in the sand when all of the sudden you look down, and you see a tortoise, Nate, it’s crawling toward you. You reach down, you flip the tortoise over on its back, Nate. The tortoise lays on its back, its belly baking in the hot sun, beating its legs trying to turn itself over, but it can’t, not without your help. But you’re not helping. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the bulk of the question has to be significantly different than the title of the question. Try extending it a bit and it should go through.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar thing happen on StackOverflow, but usually entering the CAPTCHA correctly moves me forward.  Did you type the CAPTCHA correctly? :)